# what is the impact of increasing the SecResponseBodyLimit from default value (512k) to (5M)?

Tags: mod-security

I installed the mod_security version 2.5.13 with apache2 and I'm facing problem with SecResponseBodyLimit:
( ModSecurity: Output filter: Response body too large (over limit of 524288, total not specified))

and my question is:
what is the impact of increasing the SecResponseBodyLimit from default value (512k) to (5M) ?

Answer (score 3):

It means that anything over that limit will be rejected with a 500-Internal Server Error code.

To change what it does when it hits that error the `SecResponseBodyLimitAction` directive affects that.

> By default, ModSecurity will reject a response body that is longer than specified. Some web sites, however, will produce very long responses, making it difficult to come up with a reasonable limit.

`Reject` causes the 500 error, where `ProcessPartial` allows even long responses to be allowed, but only the first part of long responses will be processed against mod_security.

https://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set/2011-April/000694.html

Comment: Will this apply to files from my server, e.g., a PDF fie?